# maven An unknown compilation problem occurred when using the @SLF4J lombox annotation

Tags: java, slf4j, lombok

I've been moving a project from one run time environment to another. As part of that process I have been restructuring classes and working to create consistency in the type and layout of the classes. We use lombok and so I was doing some work to understand the use of the SLF4J annotation in lombok.

I reached a point where I couldn't get maven to successfully compile my project. Execution of:

`$mvn clean package`

resulted in:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile 
(default-compile) on project CohortModel: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
```

The problem was that no information was available about which class, or what line was causing the problem. I've tried the usual techniques to identify the problem

```
<verbose>
```

In the maven compile plugin.

I used both

```
mvn clean package --debug
mvn -X clean package
```

Nothing provided me with any information that helped understand what was causing the compile to fail silently.  Does anyone know what caused this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of time trying way to many false leads I finally found my problem.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CohortModelService {
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log =
            org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(CohortModelService.class);
```

was the cause. I can only assume that because the logger was already in place in the log file that when lombok tried to insert the same statment into the bytecode that it failed, in a deadly and completely quite way.  The result was several hours of time spent going down numerous false paths till I finally found this duplication

Comment: Lombok does not 'insert a statement into the bytecode'; it directly modifies the AST. Presence of a `log` variable means lombok generates a compiler error message stating that you have a conflict (Both `@Slf4j` _and_ a field named `log` - that's a conflict). The error is the right reaction. (Silently ignoring this would be the wrong reaction). I don't know why maven decided to just hard crash on this, but it's not lombok's fault, or it's a bug that you should report.